# Ruby + Nokogiri - How to filter by date stored within XML element?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Given the following XML sample.

```
<Widgets>
  <Widget>
    <Price>29</Price>
    <DateAdded>02/05/2015</DateAdded>
  </Widget>
</Widgets>
```

I'm trying to find all widgets added in the last 7 days.

I tried the following:

```
widgets.xpath("//Widget[DateAdded[text()>\"#{7.days.ago}\"]]")
```

and got no love. Tried to be clever and did:

```
widgets.xpath("//Widget[(DateAdded[DateTime.parse(text())>\"#{7.days.ago}\"]]")
```

to no avail (not surprisingly, because it was a long shot!).

I'd really like to avoid iterating through entire list of Widgets and doing a date compare on each one.

Any ideas on how to make this happen please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'date'

module WidgetDate
  def date_added
    string = xpath(".//DateAdded").text
    format = "%m/%d/%Y"

    Date.strptime(string, format)
  end

  def added_within_a_week?
    (0..7).include? (Date.today - date_added)
  end
end

xml = Nokogiri::XML.parse DATA.read
widgets = xml.xpath(".//Widget").map { |widget| widget.extend WidgetDate }

result = widgets.select { |widget| widget.added_within_a_week? }

__END__
<Widgets>
  <Widget>
    <Price>16</Price>
    <DateAdded>02/11/2015</DateAdded>
  </Widget>
  <Widget>
    <Price>18</Price>
    <DateAdded>02/15/2015</DateAdded>
  </Widget>
  <Widget>
    <Price>29</Price>
    <DateAdded>02/08/2015</DateAdded>
  </Widget>
  <Widget>
    <Price>9</Price>
    <DateAdded>01/27/2015</DateAdded>
  </Widget>
  <Widget>
    <Price>36</Price>
    <DateAdded>01/03/2015</DateAdded>
  </Widget>
</Widgets>
```

**Explanation**:

1. `module` **WidgetDate** defines the methods that enable the parsed widgets  capabilities that can is useful to filter them.
2. `extend` is used to *mix* the methods defined in the module to each widgets.

Comment: Jikku, you are the man! That worked perfectly. I learned something new today. Thank you!

Comment: @Rick I too learnt like this, from many helpful people here, do remember to help as you learn :) .. Have a great day